# Why the result of "abc" term isn't included in the result of "ab" term?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm using Solr suggester to provide autocompletion for our system.
But the problem we got is:

You type **"ab"**, you get manufacturers that starts with **"ab"**.  You type **"abc"**, you got new results.
But the problem is the result of **"abc"** is a subset of **"ab"** result, so why I'm not getting the result of **"abc"** in the result of **"ab"**?

What I tried to do is to fire Lucene PrefixQuery:

```
    Term term = new Term("man", token);
    PrefixQuery prefixQuery = new PrefixQuery(term);
```

But of course this is wrong because it will get the documents whose "man" property starts with **"ab"**.  For example, I will get ten documents where "man" starts with **"ab11"**.

What I need is a list of distinct values.

And it is crazy to fire a second Solr query just to perform facetting.

I tried to achieve this with Lucene-Facet module but unfortunately, it works with categorization and taxonomy.

Personally, I'm quite happy with the result but it is hard to convince the management! :)

Comment: You haven't provided any information about your suggester configuration, so it's difficult to provide any much information to you, but that suggester results for "abc" are necessarily a subset of those "ab" is not a safe assumption.  If you only return a limitedf number of results, or result bounded by similarity thresholds, returning only more popular results, etc. the results of "abc" may be significantly less relevant than other available results to a search on "ab", and may not appear at all.